# Arrangement probabilities

Tags: probability

I worked out each part, but I am not really sure about my answers after part a.

How many different linear arrangements are there of the letters A B C D E F for which:

a. A and B are next to each other? 2!5! = 240

I grouped A and B as "one element" so now there's 5 elements, so 5! ways to arrange them, multiplied by the 2! ways to arrange AB (either AB or BA)

b. A is before B?

correct answer: 6!/2

1st attempt:

5!+4!+3!+2!+1!= 153

The way I pictured this problem is:

A _ _ _ _ _ 5! ways for B to be arranged

X A _ _ _ _ 4! ways for B to be arranged

X X A _ _ _ 3! ways for B to be arranged

X X X A _ _ 2! ways for B to be arranged

X X X X A _ 1! ways for B to be arranged

c. A is before B and B is before C?

1st attempt:

$5!4!(3!)^22!1!$

5! ways to choose letter A

4! ways to choose letter B

3! ways to choose letter C

3! ways to choose letter 4

2! ways to choose letter 5

1! way to choose letter 6

d. A is before B and C is before D?

1st attempt:

(I am not at all confident about this answer)

5!4! ways for A to be before B, then 3!2! ways for C to be before D, multiplied by 2! because we could do the reverse (5!4! ways for C to be before D, then 3!2! ways for A to be before B

e. A and B are next to each other and C and D are also next to each other? = $4!2!2!$

So I am grouping AB as "one element" and CD as one element", so there are now 4 element.

4! ways to arrange them

2! ways to arrange AB

2! ways to arrange CD

f. E is not the last in line? = $(5!)^24!3!2!1!$

5! ways to choose E

5! ways to choose letter 2

4! ways to choose letter 3

3! ways to choose letter 4

2! ways to choose letter 5

1! ways to choose letter 6

Comment: b) A is before B: by symmetry, half of $6!$; c) One sixth of $6!$; d) One quarter of $6!$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That's clever! I was going to suggest stars and bars for parts (b) and (c) because it works for both.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I understand the answer for b but could you explain c and d?

Comment: @MathMajor For (c), imagine $3$ bars separating $3$ stars, where the stars represent the letters D, E, and F, and the bars represent A, B, and C. There are $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to arrange the stars and bars together, and given this, the order of the bars is fixed and the order of the stars can be permuted in $3!=6$ ways, so the answer should be $$6\binom{6}{3} = \frac{6 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4}{3 \cdot 2} = 120$$

EDIT: André Nicolas's method works better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Good.

b) There are many ways of counting. But it is easiest to note that of the $6!$ permutations, by symmetry half have A before B and half have A after.

c) For any of the  $3!$ possible orders $\sigma$ that A, B, C can come in, there are equal numbers of permutations of A, B, C, D, E, F in which A, B, C occur in the order $\sigma$. So for the count we divide $6!$ by $3!$.

d) For a change, let's argue probabilistically. The probability that A comes before B is $\frac{1}{2}$. **Given** that A comes before B, the probability C comes before D is $\frac{1}{2}$. There are $6!$ equally likely permutations. The probability of A before B and C before D is $\frac{1}{2^2}$, so the number of "favourables" is $\frac{6!}{2^2}$.

e) Good

f) Count the complement, the words that end in E. There are $5!$ of them, so $6!-5!$ don't end in E.

Alternately, by symmetry the proportion of permutations that don't end in E is $\frac{5}{6}$.

There are only $6!$ permutations of the $6$ letters. Your proposed answer is much larger than $6!$.

**Remark:** Symmetry is your friend, exploit it. (I had better work on the wording, that didn't come out sounding quite right.)

Comment: quick question on d: why is it that the probability that A comes before B is 1/2? I know that should be obvious, but I don't quite see it

Comment: Symmetry. The events  "A before B" and "B before A" are equally likely, and their union is the whole set of permutations. Or if you want to count, there is a natural bijection between the permutations of A,B,C,D,E,F in which A is before B and the ones in which A is after B, just interchange A and B.